# how do i compare value returned from function with the given value in python

Tags: python-2.7

how do I compare the value returned from the function with the value provided by user.

```
class circle:
    def __init__(self,rad):
        self.rad=rad
    def area(self):    
        return 3.14*self.rad*self.rad
    def peri(self):
        return 2*3.14*self.rad
    def check(self,val):
        self.val=val
        if(area>val):
            print "area is greater"
        if(area<val):
            print "area is smaller"
c=circle(3)
area=c.area()
peri=c.peri()
check(50)
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: i am getting  NameError for check function

Answer (score 0):

`check` is a member function of the `circle` class - you need to call it on an instance of a `circle` - `c` in your case:

```
c.check(50)
```